# Woocommerce Orders List Output

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a table with the list of Orders but something is missing and I don't understand what it is ...
Can you help me?
My custom plugin is called "connector-wc-alma" and my output page is "testes.php" (connector-wc-alma/testes.php)

What am I missing?

Here goes the code:

```
<?php
{
    /**
     * Classe woo_export
     **/
    if (!class_exists('woo_export')) {

        class woo_export {
                
            public function __construct() {

                $this->order_status = array(
                    'completed'     => __( 'Concluída', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'cancelled'     => __( 'Cancelada', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'failed'        => __( 'Falhada', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'refunded'      => __( 'Reembolsada', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'processing'    => __( 'Processamento', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'pending'       => __( 'Pendente de Pagamento', 'woo-export-order' ),
                    'on-hold'       => __( 'Pendente de Pagamento Paypal', 'woo-export-order' ),
                );
                
                add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'export_enqueue_scripts_css' ));
                add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'export_enqueue_scripts_js' ));
            }
            
            /**
             * Funções
             */
            
            function export_enqueue_scripts_css() {
                    
                if ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'conector-wc-alma%2Ftestes.php' ) {
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'semantic', plugins_url('/css/semantic.min.css', __FILE__ ) , '', '', false);
                        
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'semanticDataTable', plugins_url('/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css', __FILE__ ) , '', '', false);

                    wp_enqueue_style( 'semanticButtons', plugins_url('/css/buttons.semanticui.min.css', __FILE__ ) , '', '', false);

                    wp_enqueue_style( 'dataTable', plugins_url('/css/data.table.css', __FILE__ ) , '', '', false);
                }
            }
            
            function export_enqueue_scripts_js(){
                
                if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'conector-wc-alma%2Ftestes.php') {
                    wp_register_script( 'dataTable', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'dataTable' );
            
                    wp_register_script( 'dataTableSemantic', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'dataTableSemantic' );

                    wp_register_script( 'dataTableButtons', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'dataTableButtons' );

                    wp_register_script( 'buttonsSemantic', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/buttons.semanticui.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'buttonsSemantic' );

                    wp_register_script( 'woo_pdfmake', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/pdfmake.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'woo_pdfmake' );

                    wp_register_script( 'jszip', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/jszip.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'jszip' );

                    wp_register_script( 'vfsfonts', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/vfs_fonts.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'vfsfonts' );

                    wp_register_script( 'buttonsHTML5', plugins_url().'/conector-wc-alma/js/buttons.html5.min.js');
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'buttonsHTML5' );
                }
            }
            
    
            function export_orders_page(){
                
                global $wpdb;
                
?>
                


<?php                   
function get_customerorderid(){
global $order, $post;

if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        $order_id = $post->ID;

        // Ir buscar a instance do object WC_Order
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    } else {
        $order_id = $order->id;
    }

    // Ir buscar o user ID à WC_Order methods
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();

return $user_id;
}
                
                
                $args = array(
                    'limit' => -1,
                );
                $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
                $var = $today_checkin_var = $today_checkout_var = $booking_time = "";
                foreach ( $orders as $id_key => $order ) {

                    //$order = wc_get_order( $id_value->order_id );

                    if ( $order->get_status() === 'processing' ) {
                        $order_items = $order->get_items();
                        
                        $my_order_meta = get_post_custom( $order->get_id() );

                        $c = 0;
                        foreach ($order_items as $items_key => $items_value ) {
                            $var .= "<tr>
    <td>".$order->get_id()."</td>
    <td>".$this->order_status[$order->get_status()]."</td>
    <td>".$my_order_meta['_billing_first_name'][0]." ".$my_order_meta['_billing_last_name'][0]."</td>
    <td style='text-align:center;'>".$order->get_user_id()."</td>
    <td>".$my_order_meta['_billing_email'][0]."</td>

    <td>".$order->get_formatted_order_total()."</td>
    <td>".$order->get_date_created()->format ('d/m/Y H:i')."</td>
    <td><a href=\"post.php?post=". $order->get_id()."&action=edit\">Encomenda</a> </td>
    <td style='text-align:center;'><a href=\"admin.php?page=nbdesigner_detail_order&download-all=true&order_id=". $order->get_id()."\">Anexos</a> </td>
    <td><a href=\"admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=processing&order_id=". $order->get_id()."&_wpnonce=c414ccf266\">Alterar p/ Em Processamento</a> </td>
    <td style='text-align:center;'><a href=\"admin.php?page=nbdesigner_detail_order&download-all=true&order_id=". $order->get_id()."\">Sincronizar</a> </td>
    </tr>";
    
                                
                            $c++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                ?>

                <script>
                    
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        var oTable = jQuery('#order_history').DataTable( {
                                //"bJQueryUI": true,
                                //"sScrollX": "",
                                "bSortClasses": false,
                                "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
                                "bAutoWidth": true,
                                "bInfo": true,
                                //"sScrollY": "100%",   
                                //"sScrollX": "100%",
                                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                "bRetrieve": true,
                                "oLanguage": {
                                                    "sSearch": "Procurar:",
                                                    "sInfo": "Mostra do registo _START_ ao _END_ num total de _TOTAL_",
                                                    "sInfoEmpty": "Sem registos",
                                                    "sZeroRecords": "Sem Encomendas para mostrar",
                                                    "sInfoFiltered": "no filtro de encomendas concluídas",
                                                    "sEmptyTable": "Sem registos",
                                                    "sLengthMenu": "Nº de Encomendas p/ páginas: _MENU_",
                                                    "oPaginate": {
                                                                    "sFirst":    "Primeira",
                                                                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                                                                    "sNext":     "Seguinte",
                                                                    "sLast":     "Ultima"
                                                                  }
                                                 },
                                //"sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                                "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                                "buttons": [
                                    'copyHtml5',
                                    'excelHtml5',
                                    'csvHtml5',
                                    'pdfHtml5'
                                ]
                    } );
                } );
                    
                           
                    </script>



            <div>
                <table id="order_history" class="ui celled table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Enc.' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Estado', 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Cliente' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'ID Cliente', 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Email', 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            
                            <th><?php _e( 'Valor' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Data' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Ver' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Download' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Acção' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Sincronizar' , 'woo-export-order' ); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php echo $var;?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            
            <?php 
                                
            }
        }
    }
    
    $woo_export = new woo_export();
}
```

Can you help me?
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you have encountered?

Comment: The page (admin.php?page=conector-wc-alma%2Ftestes.php) does not give any error, but nothing appears ...   :(

Comment: Have you consulted the server logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs... :(

Comment: Help me please!

Comment: Is the code you have shared running at all?

Comment: In the page: "admin.php?page=export_orders_page" works.... in other pages don't work...

Comment: You have a function called export_orders_page. Probably it is only called when the page you have mentioned is visited. Where is this function called?